# Forgot Password test. I get this error: in `slice!': can't convert String into Integer (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, passwords, slice

I am testing Forgot Password feature via Gmail API and having trouble slicing my result (string).

I am trying to slice a string and always get: in `slice!': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
The example below works just fine, but when I run this is a test case it fails on line 5.

```
 1 gmail = Gmail.new('email@noemail.com', 'Password')
 2 try(5) { @email = gmail.inbox.emails(:unread, :from => 'example@example.com').last }
 3 message_body = @email.message.body.raw_source
 4 pwd = message_body.scan(/Password: (?! )(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).*[^ ]$/)
    => "Password: _iDE-T!y7G\r"
 5 pwd.slice! "Password: " #slicing "Password: " 
    => "_iDE-T!y7G\r"
 6 new_pwd = pwd[0..-2] # slicing "\r"
    => "_iDE-T!y7G"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code from your test? There must be something else going on.

Comment: I've added a little bit more code, so it is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scan` returns an array, so you're not using `String#slice!` but instead `Array#slice!` which works differently.

Since you're already using a regular expression, just capture the content properly:

```
matches = message_body.scan(/Password: (?! )(.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).*[^ ]$/)

pwd = matches.flatten.first
```